# How can I drag and drop a file (not just its path) from VS Code Explorer View to system file explorer / other applications?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, drag-and-drop, nautilus

Since I've been using Ubuntu and I'm working with VS Code a lot and I need to drag and drop files from nautilus to VS Code and vise versa

the problem its only working from nautilus to VS Code and when i try from VS Code to Nautulis it copies the path not the file I tried to open VS Code with sudo still doesn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 22 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a subset of the pending set of feature requests in [Better drag and drop / clipboard integration of files across applications #164](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164), which includes [Support for native file transfer / clipboard support #2853](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2853). I suggest that you give those issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

If on the other hand you are interested in dragging the URI and not the file contents but are getting an error from the destination application, you might be interested in [Cannot drag/drop file from VS Code to other apps due to invalid data object #91132](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91132).